# How can I tell Stata which encoding to use when displaying the data in the browser and the "terminal"?

Tags: encoding, stata

I have data with string variables encoded in UTF-8 which are incorrectly displayed in (1) data browser and (2) stata "terminal" - e.g. when I type

```
list <str_var>
```

I tried to use different encodings (apart from UTF-8) but none of them worked well.

What surprises me is that the Linux version of Stata and the Mac version seem to pick different encodings.

I really want to have a smooth seamless experience in Stata when I deal with multi-lingual datasets. How can I achieve this?

Comment: "At the present time, Stata does not cope well with non-ASCII characters, such as those that would be present in UTF-8 for a language such as Czech or Turkish which contains accented characters not available in ASCII (ISO Latin-1), or those using different alphabets such as Russian or Ukranian". More in this thread: http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-04/msg01253.html

Comment: Stata actually does manage to guess the correct encoding in the linux version sometimes. That is, to some extent it can cope with such problems. I am wondering whether there is a way to help Stata pick the right encoding scheme. Perhaps there are some config files that could be tweaked

Comment: Stata 14 supports unicode - so from now on life should be easier for those of us working with strange symbols ;)